# moving a file from one folder to another in php

Tags: php, upload

i am a little stuck here.

I want to be able to move a file that has already been uploaded to another folder.

For instance:

a user uploads and it goes to a temp folder called "upload_temp/image.jpg" now i would like to move it to "resources/user_images/profile/image.jpg"

i have tried the obvious of rename() but this for some reason is not working.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing for this there is a build in php function move_uploaded_file only thing what you have to make sure that the target folder has the write privilege

Comment: @Ashish move_uploaded_file is for files that are being uploaded or am i wrong? i need it for files that have already been uploaded.

Comment: Given that `rename()` *is* the function to move files, what kind of answer are you expecting? If paths or permissions are wrong, doing it with another function will not change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Try this;-

```
chmod ("resources/user_images/profile/image.jpg", 0777);

if (copy("upload_temp/image.jpg","resources/user_images/profile/image.jpg")) {
  unlink("upload_temp/image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: no for some reason this is not work. I have not tried this live yet, its on my local in my PC using wamp. but neither the copy or rename work

Comment: i have modify my answer please try again if not working please tell me

Comment: if function not working then see this url http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=235341.0

Comment: If you could use `chmod()` to grant yourself permissions on any file, what would be the point of having permissions in the first place?